# JavaFX menubar Windows Narrator support

Tags: java, javafx, accessibility, menubar, narrator

I'm currently working on a school assignment where I need to create an app for visually impaired users. I would like to use Java with JavaFx for GUI.

Preferred element for visually impaired users is menu bar, since it can be easily navigated by keyboard. Menu bar in JavaFx is a MenuBar class object, that has Menu class attribute, which has MenuItem class attributes. Windows Narrator (neither the NVDA screen reader) works with this menu bar out of the box. It won't read the labels at all. It just says "Menu" and that's it.

Menu and MenuItem do not have accessibleText attribute which stores the text to be read by the screen reader software. Is there a way to make this menu bar screen reader compatible?

TL;DR: Is there a way to create menu bar that works with Windows Narrator in JavaFx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference: I've managed to solve this. The issue was I didn't have Java Access Bridge enabled (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/access/enable_and_test.html). Enabling it made the menu bar work without any other changes.